# SUMIF function using LARGE() as criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Could you help me creating a formula that makes it unnecessary to create the column D and gets the result using only one cell. I guess you would have to use an array formula but I can't figure it out.

[image]

I've used that formula in cell F2, but I would like to get rid of column D.

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A2:A15)=2),B2:B15)
```

Comment: I think the cell reference in the LEN formula A2:D15

Comment: no problem, you are still my hero :-)